# JavaScript forEach loop separating an array into other arrays using .push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

New here and been trying to figure this out for a bit now. Can't seem to find the answer.

Problem: trying to separate all numbers from 5 upwards into a separate array "bigNumbers". All other numbers to "smallNumbers"

Here's what I have so far:

```
let allNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; 
let bigNumbers = []; 
let smallNumbers = [];

allNumbers.forEach(function (a) {
  if(allNumbers >= 5) {
    return allNumbers.push(bigNumbers);
  } else {
    return allNumbers.push(smallNumbers);
  }
});
```

Might be taking the wrong approach entirely here using the .push() method. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Read the code.... Look at it closely First `allNumbers >= 5` you are comparing an array to be greater than five. and then you have `allNumbers.push(bigNumbers);` You are pushing the `bigNumbers` array into the `allNumbers` array. You are not pushing a value into the array. Learn basic debugging `console.log(allNumbers,5, allNumbers>=5)` that will show you what is happening on the if.

Comment: try `bigNumbers .push(a);` and `smallNumbers.push(a)` instead. and check `if (a >= 5) ` instead as well

Comment: Inside your `.forEach()` callback you should be referring to `a`, not `allNumbers`

Comment: remove `return` and also change the if to check `a`

Comment: Right `return` is pointless because `.forEach()` ignores return values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're testing the wrong variable, it should be `a`, not `allNumbers`. And the argument to `.push()` is the value you want to push onto the array, not the array to push onto. There's also no need to use `return`, since `forEach` doesn't use the return values.

```js
let allNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; 
let bigNumbers = []; 
let smallNumbers = [];

allNumbers.forEach(function (a) {
  if(a >= 5) {
     bigNumbers.push(a);
  } else {
     smallNumbers.push(a);
  }
});

console.log("Big: " + JSON.stringify(bigNumbers));
console.log("Small: " + JSON.stringify(smallNumbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Trouble is in your `if (allNumbers >= 5)`

What you want is to know if the current number being iterated is greater than 5:

```
if (a >= 5)...
```

Comment: There are more problems than just the comparison.

Comment: Right, return is not necessary in forEach